# Video playback on mobile: can't seek to the end

Tags: unity, mobile, video

My Unity3D game needs to play videos on mobile devices (using `Handheld.PlayFullscreenMovie()`). Seeking works badly. If I tap the video progress bar near the end (expecting it to play the last second then finish), playback jumps back a full 10-20 seconds, depending on the video. What should I try to make it easier for the player to seek within the file? Force additional key frames?

I'm currently encoding with HandbrakeCLI and the following settings:

```
--preset="AppleTV" --x264-tune=animation --x264-preset=veryslow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using x264 encoding, your most likely problem is keyframes*. See [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/linuxencoding/x264-ffmpeg-mapping) and search for keyframe (it's the first thing there). Of course, you're not using FFmpeg, so you need the [options for HandbrakeCLI](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/cli-options.html), which seems to be "-x" [command](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/cli-guide.html) (a.k.a. --encopts) which receives a string, [detailed here](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/video-qsv-options.html). Try those options out.

(`--encopts "keyint=60"` sets the maximum GOP size to 60 frames, which should make (at least) every 2 seconds searchable for a 30FPS video but that would also mean much lower compression)

*[Keyframes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame) are used for compression and you can only search between keyframes in a x264 compression (Jump from one keyframe to another). It is most likely a really high number by default for extreme compression.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. But the option name has changed, and the syntax is wrong--HandbrakeCLI uses the same syntax for its long and short options. I hope you don't mind if I edit your answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's cool. I don't really have any experience with HandlebrakeCLI, so your edit is more than welcome.